# Transition effect between two states of svg polygon on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, transition

```js
function menuHover(navLI, Y) {
    const topTriangle = navLI.querySelector(".triangle").querySelector("polygon");
    topTriangle.setAttribute("points", "0,0 200,0 100," + Y);
}

function navHoverIn(navLI) {menuHover(navLI, 60);}
function navHoverOut(navLI) {menuHover(navLI, 10);}
```

```html
<div onmouseenter="navHoverIn(this)" onmouseleave="navHoverOut(this)">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 60" class="triangle">
    <polygon points="0,0 200,0 100,10">
  </svg>
</div>
```

If you hover over the triangle, the coordinate points of the polygon change.
Any ideas what is the most convenient way to create the transition effect between the two states? So it doesn't just instantly change, but has some kind of ease animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all this in [SMIL](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html). No javascript required.

```html
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 60" class="triangle">
    <polygon points="0,0 200,0 100,10">
      <animate begin="mouseover" attributeName="points" to="0,0 200,0 100,60" dur="1s" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/>
      <animate attributeName="points" begin="mouseout" dur="1s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" to="0,0 200,0 100,10"/>
    </polygon>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at SMIL! Although might be an issue as a separate element is a trigger for hover, not the triangle itself.

Comment: It was not an issue, looks like you can use a different element as a trigger by referring to its id. As long as it's a part of the same SVG anyway.